# Why are neutrino flavour eigenstates expressed in terms of the elements of the complex conjugate of the PMNS matrix?

Tags: particle-physics, conventions, neutrinos, linear-algebra

If we have

$$
                \begin{pmatrix}
                \nu_e\\ \nu_{\mu} \\ \nu_{\tau}
                \end{pmatrix}
                =\begin{pmatrix}
                  U_{e1} & U_{e2} & U_{e3} \\
                  U_{\mu1} & U_{\mu2} & U_{\mu3} \\
                  U_{\tau1} & U_{\tau2} & U_{\tau3}
                  \end{pmatrix}
                  \begin{pmatrix}
                  \nu_1 \\ \nu_2 \\ \nu_3
                  \end{pmatrix},\tag{1}
$$

then why are flavour eigenstates expressed using the complex conjugated elements of the PMNS matrix:

$$
                 |\nu_{\alpha}\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^3U_{\alpha i}^*|\nu_i\rangle,
$$
(where $\alpha = e,\ \mu,\ \tau$) rather than
$$
                 |\nu_{\alpha}\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^3U_{\alpha i}|\nu_i\rangle,
$$
as suggested by $(1)$. Wouldn't it make more sense to define the PMNS matrix as its complex conjugate in the first place?

Comment: What you suggest is done in case of anti-neutrinos.

Comment: Essential [duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/412096/if-u-determines-the-mixing-between-fields-and-u-determines-the-mixing-betw?noredirect=1&lq=1).