# If $U$ determines the mixing between fields and $U^*$ determines the mixing between states-Why?

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

In [this](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2017/reviews/rpp2017-rev-neutrino-mixing.pdf) pdg review, Eq. (14.1), the mixing between the flavour neutrino fields and neutrino fields corresponding to mass eigenstates are denoted as $$\nu_{lL}=\sum\limits_{j}U_{lj}\nu_{jL}\tag{1}$$ where $U$ stands for the neutrino mixing matrix. On the other hand, the mixing between flavour eigenstates and mass eigenstates, in Eq. (14.27), is given by $$|\nu_{lL}\rangle=\sum\limits_{j}U^*_{lj}|\nu_{jL}\rangle\tag{2}.$$

Why did they use $U$ in Eq.(14.1) and its complex conjugate $U^*$ in Eq.(14.27)? I guess this is not a typo because I have seen it at other places as well.

[One](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/392394/why-are-neutrino-flavour-eigenstates-expressed-in-terms-of-the-elements-of-the-c) of the questions tagged by AccidentalFourierTransform in the comment below, asks about conventions. My question is not about the convention. Having fixed $U$ for the mixing between fields, should I use $U^*$ for mixing between states? Or, having fixed $U^*$ for the mixing between fields, should I use $U$ for mixing between states?

Comment: same question, no answers: [Why are neutrino flavour eigenstates expressed in terms of the elements of the complex conjugate of the PMNS matrix?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/392394/84967), and the (now deleted) question by OP, [Is the neutrino flavour mixing between fields or states?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/406491/84967).

Comment: There is also a feeble excuse that a field destroys the state with the same labels, but   most practitioners shrug it off and simply check the self-consistency of their calculations.

Comment: @CosmasZachos My question is, if the mixing between fields is governed by $U$, will the mixing between states also governed by $U$?

Comment: *Of course* !! The field just destroys a particle with the same name and creates an antiparticle with the C  q-numbers.

Comment: I would guess that it is because, as mentioned already, a neutrino field _annihilates_ neutrinos. To get the phases to match up for the states, you can work with antineutrino fields instead, since they create neutrinos. But the antineutrino fields are related by $U^*$, not $U$.

Comment: @knzhou Aha! That makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Field operators are defined so that they annihilate states. That is,
$$ \langle \Omega | \nu_{i\, L}(x) | \nu_{j,L}(\vec{p})\rangle = \delta_{ij} u(\vec{p}) e^{-ipx}$$

Hence, if the theory is invariant under the transformation $\nu_{i,L}(x) \mapsto U_{ik}\nu_{k,L}(x)$ with $U$ unitary, then we must have $|\nu_j\rangle \mapsto U^†_{lj} |\nu_l \rangle$ so that
$$\langle \Omega| \nu'_i(x) |\nu'_j\rangle = U_{ik}U^†_{lj}\langle\Omega |\nu_k|\nu_l\rangle = U_{ik}U^†_{lj}\delta_{kl} = (UU^†)_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$$

Another way of looking at is that it is the conjugate field operator that creates the state, ie $|\nu_i\rangle \propto \nu^†_i(x)|\Omega\rangle$. So if the field transforms as $U$, then the states should transform as $U^*$.